# String find and replace

Tags: c#

I have a string like

```
string text="~aaa~bbb~ccc~bbbddd";
```

The input value will be : **bbb**

So in the above string i should remove the value **"~bbb"**

The resulting string should be

```
text="~aaa~ccc~bbbddd";
```

Comment: Have you tried searching? A quick Google for "C# string replace" should find the [`String.Replace()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)... Likewise for removing sections, the [`String.Remove()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx).

Comment: explain pls what you want ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you wanna do but if i've got it you can do this :

```
private string ReplaceFirstOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
{
 int Place = Source.IndexOf(Find);
 string result = Source.Remove(Place, Find.Length).Insert(Place, Replace);
 return result;
}

var result =ReplaceFirstOccurrence(text,"~"+input,"");
```

Comment: the result should be `~aaa~ccc~bbbddd` but your's is : `~aaa~cccddd`

Comment: Your method will also replace the last part. So "~aaa~bbb~ccc~bbbddd" will become "~aaa~cccddd".

Comment: This will not work. it will replace the `bbb` in the last segment as well.

Comment: you right i didn't see the last ~bbb so i update my post to correct solution

Answer (score 4):

One way would be:

```
string text = "~aaa~bbb~ccc~bbbddd";
string newStr = string.Join("~", text.Split('~').Where(r => r != "bbb"));
```

But if performance is the consideration then consider some other solution

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
string searchValue = "bbb";
text = text.Replace(String.Format("~{0}~", searchValue), "~");
```

Be sure to search for the ending ~ character as well, otherwise you will also replace part of ~bbbddd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression @"\bMYWORDTOREPLACE\b" in c# this would be...

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\bbbb\b", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
string str = "~rajeev~ravi";
string strRemove = "rajeev";
string strNew =str.Replace("~"+strRemove ,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Replace(this String str, char[] chars, string replacement)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        bool replace = false;
        if (chars.Length - 1 < 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {

                char c = str[i];
                replace = false;
                //  int val = Regex.Matches(ch.ToString(), @"[a-zA-Z]").Count;


                for (int j = 0; j < chars.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (chars[j] == c)
                    {
                        replace = true;

                        break;

                    }

                }

                if (replace)
                    output.Append(replacement);
                else
                    output.Append(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            int j = 0;
            int truecount = 0;
                char c1 = '\0';
                for (int k = 0; k < str.Length; k++)
                {
                   c1 = str[k];

                    if (chars[j] == c1)
                    {
                        replace = true;
                        truecount ++;


                    }

                    else
                    {
                        truecount = 0;
                        replace = false;
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    if(truecount>0)
                    {
                        j++;
                    }

                    if (j > chars.Length-1)
                    {
                        j = 0;
                    }

                    if (truecount == chars.Length)
                    {
                        output.Remove(output.Length - chars.Length+1, chars.Length-1);
                       // output.Remove(4, 2);
                        if (replace)
                            output.Append(replacement);
                        else
                            output.Append(c1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.Append(c1);
                    }


                }

        }


        return output.ToString();
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
    string word = (Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to find");
    string find = (Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to Replace");
    string Rep = (Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(Replace(word, find.ToCharArray(), Rep));
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but my solution is to create extension function for string.
Like ".ReplaceFirst" Java method.

You need to create static class like Helper and inside that class create static extension function:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string ReplaceFirst(this String str, string find, string replace)
    {
        int place = str.IndexOf(find);
        if (place < 0)
        {
            return str;
        }
        //return str.Substring(0, place) + replace + str.Substring(place + find.Length);
        return str.Remove(place, find.Length).Insert(place, replace);
    }
}
```

Usage is same like .Replace method...

```
string text="~aaa~bbb~ccc~bbbddd";
string temp = text.ReplaceFirst("~bbb", ""); //text="~aaa~ccc~bbbddd"
```

or more

```
string text="~aaa~bbb~ccc~bbbddd";
string temp = text.ReplaceFirst("~bbb", "").ReplaceFirst("~bbb", ""); //text="~aaa~cccddd"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could do something like this.
(You only need to input 'bbb')

```
string text  = "~aaa~bbb~ccc~bbbddd";
string input = "bbb";                

string output = text.Replace("~" + input + "~", "~");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output: `~aaa~ccc~bbbddd`